# D3.js: How to highlight nodes in Dendogram with particular color?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use D3.js [cluster](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout) to build [Dendogram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570) and I want to highlight particular nodes. I thought I could achieve this adding custom attribute `color` to each node of a tree and then write something like this:

```
node.append("text").attr("fill", function(d) {return d.color})
```

But it seems that there are only [standard predefined attributes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout#wiki-nodes) in tree node.
Now I'm not sure this approach is right.

So how can I highlight particular nodes depending on custom color attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
I've managed to implement this by encapsulating custom attribute inside name attribute. I think it may be helpful to show the code:

```
node.append("text")
.attr("fill", function(d) {return d.name.split(':').pop()})
.text(function (d) {
  var tokens = d.name.split(':');
  return tokens.slice(0, tokens.length-1);
});
```

Here I use name attribute with the following format: `"name:color"`. And then I use first part as text and second part as color.